# iphone force portrait mode from landscape?

Tags: iphone

I have a complicated structure where I have a custom tab-bar controller that houses multiple navigation controllers. Some of these sub-navigation controllers only support portrait mode so I just turn off rotation when I get to them. When I come into the new navigation controller and it is in landscape is there a way to force auto-rotation to portrait at that time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple is no longer allowing private method calls, they're running the apps through static analysis now when they're submitted.  If you submit a new app using `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:]` it will be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the undocumented method `setOrientation:` from the `UIDevice` class. Here is one example:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

*You will have one compiler warning, ignore it.*

I do not have problem with Apple rejection using this method, so until now it works.